# a C++ syntax error when passing class members in a constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I need to write a kind of shared_ptr<> in C++. However, I'm now struggling with a weird error.
The following code:

```
template <typename T> class shared_ptr;
typedef std::map<void*, shared_ptr<void*>> ptr_t;
ptr_t ptr_set;
template <typename T> class shared_ptr
{
    T* ptr;
public:
    bool in_use;
    shared_ptr<T>()
    {
        ptr = new T;
        in_use = false;
        ptr_set.insert(ptr_t::value_type(ptr, *this)); // the error is here
    }
    T operator*()
    {
        return *ptr;
    }
    shared_ptr<T>(shared_ptr<T>& ref)
    {
        this->in_use = false;
        this->ptr = ref.ptr;
        T* p = this->ptr;
        ptr_set.insert(ptr_t::value_type(p, *this));
    }
};
```

refuses to compile saying 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair: none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types' (C2665 in the 13th line actually).
By the way, shared_ptr is instantiated in main() as `shared_ptr<array_t> a`, where `array_t` is a struct consisting of nothing more than a simple array (I don't think this is the actual source of the bug). Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. The answer's been edited to fix a typo (p instead of ptr at line 13).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you'll get an error, because `shared_ptr< T* >` cannot be casted to `shared_ptr< void* >` except `T` is `void`. To solve it you can add a casting operator to your `shared_ptr` class, that will cast any type to `shared_ptr< void* >`

Answer (score 0):

The line with the error refers to `p` which has not been declared. Did you mean to say `ptr`?